# pe:blockUI file.gif don't work

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm using the blockUI component of the Primefaces extensions framework.
The .gif file does not work: it is a still image that is displayed.
Thanks for your help.

```
<pe:blockUI widgetVar="widgetPatienter" content="idPatienter" target="idColPlanCompteM61" cssOverlay="{opacity: 0}"/>

<p:outputPanel id="idPatienter" style="display: none">  
     <h:graphicImage value="images/Sablier.gif" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 10px"/>    
     <h:outputText value = "Merci de patienter..."/>    
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: So you **do** see the `h:outputText`?

Comment: sorry but I did not understand

Comment: You state the GIF does not work but you also have an outputText in the panel. Does THAT show?

Comment: I want to display the .gif + outputText

Comment: sorry my support supports ends here

Answer (score 0):

See this example:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/blockui/blockUIAjax.jsf

Your target has to be something that uses Ajax events.  in the example above it triggers on datatable Ajax events.  in your case I can't see what your `target="idColPlanCompteM61"` is pointing to?

Comment: Even removing style = "display: none" Sablier.gif does not work

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: <p:dataTable id="idColPlanCompteM61" 
...
<p:ajax event="page" onstart="PF('widgetPatienter').block()" oncomplete="PF('widgetPatienter').unblock()"/>                               
<p:ajax event="sort" onstart="PF('widgetPatienter').block()" oncomplete="PF('widgetPatienter').unblock()"/>